# Session token as a part of the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Let's suppose I want to use routing like this:

```
{sessionid}/{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

Adding a route is easy enough, but now I am unclear on how to get `AuthorizeAttribute` to use the user associated with my session token. I looked at its source in ILSpy, and it seem to be relying on `HttpContext` to get `IPrincipal`, and that's where trail goes cold.
Where does it get this instance of `IPrincipal`?

Worst case I imagine I could write a custom `FilterAttribute` and a custom user class implementing `IPrincipal`. Hook it up globally to get `sessionid` from the route data, look up my user from DB and then just give my custom `IPrincipal` instance to `HttpContext.User`.
This seems a bit low level and also bypassing the whole `MembershipProvider` business.

Am I on the right track or maybe there is an easier way to go about this?

Comment: Side note: putting auth info in Url is bad idea since everyone sees the urls (i.e. as referer, or just user copy-paste one...)

Comment: I remember in web forms development that you could specify cookielessMode in the web.config which made it prepend something to the url.  have you tried that?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I know it is not optimal, but I have very specific requirements for this

Comment: @Slicksim that doesn't really help me to connect my `sessionid` with ASP.NET authentication

Comment: I think you can't find what you are looking for because you are looking in wrong place - authentication in ASP.Net done earlier in pipeline before MVC part kicks in - search http://www.bing.com/search?q=asp.net+AuthenticateRequest should give you good starting point to understand that (and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555126/asp-net-mvc-custom-iprincipal-injection) question that seem to be close to yours). One need to *authenticate* user first before *authorizing* to perform an action.