# How to filter connections to controllers in ASP.NET MVC 4 web-app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, filter

**Context:**
Each account includes rights (privileges), these rights allow him to do this or that action. I can not use the RoleProvider here because it will be very difficult to manage, view there is about 5! possible roles.

So using filters on access to controllers would be the best way to deal with this.

How do I to use filters? How would I implement this? Any example or link to a tutorial showing  how to deal with this, please?

Comment: What exactly does your "filter connections" means? Filter by client IP? Or some specific request header? Or something else? Please specify.

Comment: @WeTTTT, I was talkin about [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iauthorizationfilter(v=vs.118).aspx).

Comment: If I understand you right, may be you need this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21749772/1534785